# Helm range only getting last value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want multiple containers in the deployment template so I am just iterating over the `values.yaml` and had put the container configuration in the range loop.

`values.yaml`

```yaml
images:
  image1:
    name: "hjdsh"
    repository: nginx
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
    tag: ""
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
  image2:
    name: "kjbjk"
    repository: nginx
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
    tag: ""
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
```

`_deployment.yaml`

```yaml
{{- define "common-helm.deployment.tpl" -}}
{{- $requiredMsg := include "common.default-check-required-msg" . -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "common.name"  .}}
  labels:
    {{- include "common.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas:  {{ .Values.deploymentReplicas }}
  {{- end }}
  minReadySeconds: {{ .Values.deployment.minReadySeconds | default 0 }}
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{- include "common.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{- include "common.labels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.gitlab.auth.enabled }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ include "common.fullname" . }}-gitlab-auth
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.serviceAccount.name | quote }}
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: {{ .Values.deployment.runAsUser | default 1000 }}
        runAsUser: {{ .Values.deployment.runAsUser | default 1000 }}
        runAsNonRoot: {{ .Values.deployment.runAsNonRoot | default true }}
        affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              - labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - {{ include "common.fullname" . }}
                topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        containers:

{{- range $key, $value := .Values.images}}
          -name: {{ $value.name }}_{{ $key }}
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1200
          image: {{ $value.repository }}
          imagePullPolicy: ""
          ports:
            -containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: {{ $value.resources.requests.memory }}
              cpu: {{ $value.resources.requests.cpu }}
            limits:
              memory: {{ $value.resources.limits.memory }}
              cpu: {{ $value.resources.limits.cpu }}
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /v1/healthCheck
              port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: ""
          periodSeconds: 10

  {{- end }}
{{- end  }}
{{- define "common-helm.deployment" -}}
{{- include "common-helm.util.merge" (append . "common-helm.deployment.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
```

**outcome**: it only creates a container for the last image.

[image]

It was expected to create two containers with both images.

Comment: Hi! Please replace images with text. It'll be easier for others to copy/paste and reproduce the issue. Regarding your issue, did you try to debug it yourself? See https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/ and the `print` function (https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#print) should also be helpful to track this issue on your side.

Comment: I wouldn't try to put every possible bit of Kubernetes-level configuration in the `values.yaml` file; instead, just go ahead and create multiple `templates/*-deployment.yaml` files, one for each Deployment you need to create, and put most-to-all of the settings there.  (It should be unusual to have multiple containers in the same Pod.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I know it's unusual but I need multiple containers in single pod for a particular requirement

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use an array of images instead of objects, and to follow closely the Helm documentation example: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action

```yaml
images:
- name: wqqwd1
  container: nginx
- name: wqqwd2
  container: nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `_deployment.yaml` contains formatting and indentation issues. You need to fix those first. Also, follow the official [debugging instructions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/) to verify the rendered changes. For debugging, you may also use the [`print`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#print) function.

Here's a small example [tested online](https://helm-playground.com/#t=JYWwhg5gpgzgXAKAN5ILQAIBOYB210AkA1gDSEBu6cAvOgHQBqYANgK6x2iSzoC%2BvCDDjAgocdCgp1hovrwD6k4nITp0XaOKXk6mKAAcA9jGAAXQ5gCeKlBig4AJiqA&v=JYWwhg5gpgzgXAKAARNJKBGRKUDswhRyobI4BOUADgPYzAAuN5AnseaSmtAEzY75CxYDzIpKtek1btRQA) and it works fine:

`template.yaml`

```yaml
images:
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.images }}
- name: {{ $v.name }}_{{ $k }}
  image: {{ $v.repository }}
{{- end }}
```

`values.yaml`

```yaml
images:
  image1:
    name: i1
    repository: r1
  image2:
    name: i2
    repository: r2
```

**Output**

```yaml
images:
- name: i1_image1
  image: r1
- name: i2_image2
  image: r2
```

---

**UPDATE**

After reducing the updated config (as text) to bareminimum, it is working fine. See it online [here](https://helm-playground.com/#t=IYBwlgagpgTgzmA9gOwFwAJQjgegG4CMAUANZjIAmGAIlCADaICeAtlMgC5FwhQDGqIunQcoLBsFGDhwnv2kzhfFB2DlYcBYoDe2gLToYwZAHMo6ACQkoTADSW8wegFdzqALzoAdBCeu4XmAswGZw6AC%2B4UKK6AbIwGwYug5%2BUF7xbBHhAPrJVjZZ0THocPzOMGAcTADCKlAAHhxaxYbOyACCcAByKABKiIhNIjCuRS0jHXAAqqUwGAQATAAMS2OKQSFQSdopLmkwdIgIHIgwTIUt6BtmAArO9PQ3iPRgfEzbu65eIPePz6-nSJrGQgU4cTTA4QGZScNTIWBPGBDAAcS1RkMMUDgiHKfCxHxOAE0EvRPvssTiYHiwgAfdDIcgUdgcdAEJYXGK6AzsChZIA&v=JYWwhg5gpgzgXAKAARNJKBGRKUDswhRxIBEAFgFYAmMZJyOATlAA4D2MwALm4wJ7FcEYLgAeDFCwCuAGxkAFNjOABjAUgCSAMwBybLvOYwouLhKRdIxEvRypc3YGBkARKDLB8AylBVtcNMQArOZGbFKMKrDYdkjMAI5SsFzw5naEILzqJBgATAAcALLAtrEoKtLWefkgpXbKINypZSgZWVUFxXWxFVIdNaVo0LkxeAREpADWFABGFJPdzOycPPyCwmLm0nKKymrE2noGRiZmdpYQ1t0ijs5uHt6%2B-oFIIXZhEVHNsQlJMCmjWJtNakapdNI4Xr9WoQhpNQHpKCZEE5TolCHlSqggowoA).

`template.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: name
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.deploymentReplicas }}
  {{- end }}
  minReadySeconds: {{ .Values.deployment.minReadySeconds | default 0 }}
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.gitlab.auth.enabled }}
      imagePullSecrets:
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.serviceAccount.name | quote }}
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: {{ .Values.deployment.runAsUser | default 1000 }}
        runAsUser: {{ .Values.deployment.runAsUser | default 1000 }}
        runAsNonRoot: {{ .Values.deployment.runAsNonRoot | default true }}
        affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              - labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        containers:
        {{- range $key, $value := .Values.images }}
        - name: {{ $value.name }}_{{ $key }}
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1200
          image: {{ $value.repository }}
          imagePullPolicy: ""
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: {{ toYaml $value.resources | nindent 10 }}
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /v1/healthCheck
              port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: ""
          periodSeconds: 10
        {{- end }}
```

`values.yaml`

```yaml
images:
  image1:
    name: "hjdsh"
    repository: nginx
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: ""
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
  image2:
    name: "kjbjk"
    repository: nginx
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: ""
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "128m"
```

**Output**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: name
spec:
  replicas: <no value>
  minReadySeconds: 0
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: 
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              - labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
        containers:
        - name: hjdsh_image1
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1200
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: ""
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: 
          limits:
            cpu: 128m
            memory: 128Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 128m
            memory: 128Mi
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /v1/healthCheck
              port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: ""
          periodSeconds: 10
        - name: kjbjk_image2
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1200
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: ""
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: 
          limits:
            cpu: 128m
            memory: 128Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 128m
            memory: 128Mi
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /v1/healthCheck
              port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: ""
          periodSeconds: 10
```

Your issue might be coming from someplace else. You need to debug the rest of the template and fix any intermediate issues that are causing this. As there are `include` also so it cannot be reproduced in entirety without them.

Comment: I am using it the same way as you mentioned but it only have last image in the output

Comment: @NeerajYadav: Please edit your question and add the relevant config as text. That'll be easier to iterate over. I'll verify that once you update it.

Comment: I have added the code, not able to put values.yaml in correct format. It might help

Comment: @NeerajYadav: Please check the updated part of this answer. Thanks!